# Как хранить уникальные значения в таблице MуSQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, архитектура

Есть таблица с котировками, данных много - около 15 млн. записей, необходимо получать уникальные значения пар. Вопрос: оставить так и брать просто уникальные значения через `distinct`, или сделать отдельную таблицу для названий значений? Если делать отдельную таблицу, как оперативно обновлять данные? Триггером?

Comment: что из себя представляют названия и значения?

Comment: А какой смысл в неуникальных записях? удалить их, и всего делов... а каждый раз дистинктить - это у тебя сервер больше ничего делать не сможет.

Comment: удалить нельзя, это лог того что приходит в другую базу, заполняется триггером, может я что-то не так объяснил или может данных мало? По уникальным полям потом делается выборка чтобы заполнить селект на сайте

Comment: Обычно запись о котировке содержит кроме всего прочего и штамп времени котировки. Если таковой имеется, и в том, что Вы полагаете дубликатом, различается - то это НЕ дубликаты. А если его нет, или и он тоже совпадает - то это полные дубликаты, и нет никакого смысла их хранить. Вам же нужны котировки, а вовсе не сведения о том, сколько раз эта котировка попала в базу...

Comment: Дубликаты именно они, проблема в том что сигналы приходят обрабатываются и уходят дальше, потом таблица чиститься и забивается новыми данными, всегда в базе только 6 сигналов а надо хранить всю историю, поэтому и делаются дубликаты, теперь надо делать выборку по этим данным, соответственно надо сделать селект с парами, как мне это сделать? Читайте первый пост, думаю так будет понятней

Comment: зачем вы заполняете селект из лога?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Не надо никаких отдельных таблиц (если агрегация несложная)

В документации MySQL [упоминается "Loose Index Scan" (раздел 9.2.1.16.1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html), который позволяет быстро получить из индекса по `(a, b, c)` уникальные значения по `(a, b)` с максимальным/минимальным `c` попросту путём взятия "крайних элементов" из каждой группы (bucket) в индексе. Это произойдёт при самом обычном `SELECT MAX(c) ... GROUP BY a, b`.

Это частный случай, в документации условия такого обхода описаны точнее, но это покрывает очень распространённый сценарий: для каждого значения некоторых ключей достать самое "свежее" значение.

Таким образом, чтобы быстро получать уникальные по парам `a, b` агрегированные по `MIN`/`MAX` столбца `c`, нужно сделать составной индекс по столбцам `a, b, c` (`b, a, c`, возможно, тоже прокатит, `a, b, c, d` тоже). (Возможно, стоит даже сделать его первичным ключом, но лучше проверить, есть ли в этом смысл.)

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте таблицу с уникальным индексом по нужной паре полей и добавляйте в неё новые записи через `INSERT IGNORE` или `… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Тогда вам не понадобится ни GROUP BY, ни DISTINCT при выборке.

Если вам требуется иметь как полный лог, так и "агрегированные" значения, держите две таблицы и в одну транзакцию пополняйте их обе.

См. https://stackoverflow.com/q/548541/272885

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю